# getting pid of process in windows server

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-server-2008

I was looking for a script to get PID of a java process based on CommandLine value of task manager. ALl these java processes have similar COmmandLine value but differ in a keyword within the CommandLine. The process can't be identified by the image name because they all have same java.exe. Is there a way? I've placed below code based on npocmaka's answer

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "command_line="%1""

set "command_line=!command_line:"=%%!"

echo ~~!command_line!~~

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%# in (
    `wmic process where 'CommandLine like "%command_line%"' get /format:value`
) do (
    for /f %%$ in ("%%#") do (
        set "%%$"
    )
)

echo %ProcessId%
```

I'm using a keyword in CommandLine to identify the PID. Yet when I execute this script, I get the wrong PID. I'm assuming its returning the scripts PID as the script may also contain the keyword. The argument while executing the script is taken as keyword

Comment: What is "CommandLine value of task manager"?

Comment: I've edited my post. It contains the answer

Comment: probably there are more processes with the same command line.Try with `echo %%$` instead of `set %%$` to see how many processes will apply the wmic query,

Comment: I see two sets of values. One set which starts with "Caption=java.exe"  and another set with "Caption=WMIC.exe". So its wmic.exe pid its returning. ANy idea how to get for other one

Comment: @Master_Roshy check my edit (in the answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`WMIC PROCESS`](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) is what you need.Though you'll need some tricks to use it from batch.I've used more complex command line which contains quotes ,brackets,spaces, file separators.... You'll need to change it and set the value you want.

First you'll need to double every backslash in the command line(the script should do it I mean).Quotes also can be a problem and need to be replaced  with `%` or escaped with `\"` (`WMIC` uses `WQL` a [subset of](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx) `SQL` commands and `%` is used as wildcard).Another thing is you need to process the result twice with `FOR` [loop to rid-off unwanted special characters](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4266).`/Format:Value` can be used for direct declaring variable/value pairs.So here it is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: !!!!!!!!!
set "command_line="C:\Program Files (x86)\Dropbox\Client\Dropbox.exe" /systemstartup"
:: !!!!!!!!

set "command_line=!command_line:\=\\!"
set "command_line=!command_line:"=%%!"
::or
::set "command_line=!command_line:"=\"!"


rem echo ~~!command_line!~~

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%# in (
    `wmic process where 'CommandLine^="!command_line!"' get /format:value`
) do (
    for /f %%$ in ("%%#") do (
        set "%%$"
    )
)

echo %ProcessId%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 wmic process where name='explorer.exe' get commandline, pid /format:list
```

is one way. Also see `tasklist /v`.